# Add Realm database in Flutter project created with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, flutter, realm

I'm creating a project with Android Studio and I want to store data in local.

I don't want to use SQLite for my database and I wish I knew if it'is possible to use Realm database in Flutter project.

Answer (score 5):

Realm support is blocked by https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7053 (see also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7053#issuecomment-369884221)

This is work in progress and it was mentioned that it might become available this quarter.

Comment: Oooh Thanks @Günter! I (we) still wait for. I love using Realm instead SQLite for project.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is it better to use `jaguar_orm 2.2.5` instead of `SQFlite`?

Comment: I don't know jaguar_orm, but I guess it needs sqflite anyway to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [flutter_mongodb_realm](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mongodb_realm) package.

Connect it like:

```
main() async{
  // ADD THESE 2 LINES
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await RealmApp.init(<your_app_id>);
  
  // other configurations..
  
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```